# Get number of AD errors with LDAP and PHP (ldap function return unprecise error)

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I'm making an application with uses PHP to connect to Active Directory (AD), using LDAP protocol.

Works fine, my problem is how to catch the specific errors if the login operations fails. Today, the application only shows if the login worked or not, example: suppose that the username is expired in AD, the system will show that the "username/password is invalid" because we don't verify specific returns of LDAP.

Ok, let's go to the problem itself, below is my code that I expect to catch specific errors.

```
<?php
if (! ($bind = @ldap_bind ( $connect, "DOMAIN\\" . strtoupper ( $this->user), $this->password))) {
            error_log ( "Autentication fails LDAP (user: $this->user)" );

            return ldap_errno ( $connect );
?>
```

That function, ldap_errno, returns me the number of what happened, based on this table:

(There are more, see link below)

48  LDAP_INAPPROPRIATE_AUTH
49  LDAP_INVALID_CREDENTIALS
49 / 52e    AD_INVALID CREDENTIALS
49 / 525    USER NOT FOUND
49 / 530    NOT_PERMITTED_TO_LOGON_AT_THIS_TIME
49 / 531    RESTRICTED_TO_SPECIFIC_MACHINES 
49 / 532    PASSWORD_EXPIRED
49 / 533    ACCOUNT_DISABLED
49 / 568    ERROR_TOO_MANY_CONTEXT_IDS
49 / 701    ACCOUNT_EXPIRED
49 / 773    USER MUST RESET PASSWORD
50  LDAP_INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS

http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=LDAP_Error_Codes

Ok, the problem is that PHP returns me always only 49 (LDAP_INVALID_CREDENTIALS), independent of the situation (situation where have relation with login). Example, if my account is expired, PHP returns me 49, I want that return 49 / 701, how I can find the 701? Is another function?

And how I show to the user if his password OR his username is invalid, not both? I know it is a point of security to show that both is invalid, but we decide that is better show what is wrong, if username or if is password, is possible to know with LDAP?

PHP Version 5.4.31

**EDIT**

I have found an issue that can be useful:

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47222

Anyone know how to do a ldap_search in this way:

```
ldapsearch -x -H ldap://der-ad-server.de:389 -D accountname@der-ad-server.de -W
```

I don't know how to make this search with PHP `ldap_search()` function

Comment: You do not show the user whether the username OR the password were wrong!  If you'd do that an attacker could easily check for a username and then for a password using a bruteforce attack. As soon as you only say "one of username and password is wrong" you can't say which. Therefore hacking the system is much more difficult.

Comment: Ok, I know. But, is there a way to do that?

Comment: I also found below mentioned solution and wrapped it in a nice function. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37188629/1059828

Comment: @abimelex hey, nice! It would be good if the title was more associated with ldap diagnostic errors :).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After spend a lot of hours in search I found the solution!

I have founded in this page : 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-get-option.php

basically you have to define a new constant variable called **LDAP_OPT_DIAGNOSTIC_MESSAGE**

like this

```
define('LDAP_OPT_DIAGNOSTIC_MESSAGE', 0x0032);
```

and then

```
ldap_get_option($conn, LDAP_OPT_DIAGNOSTIC_MESSAGE, $extended_error);
```

With that, LDAP will give you extended error and you will be able to know what really happened, the value will be put in $extended_error.